# Flutter: Device orientation doesn't dispose in Splash Screen

Tags: flutter, dispose, device-orientation

***I used custom device orientation on my splash screen (it's worked) and try to back it normal by use dispose(). But it doesn't work.***

---

> Here is my Code-

---

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:boimarket/widgets/exitpopup.dart';
import 'package:boimarket/homepage.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 3),
        () => Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ExitPopUp(Homepage()))));
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Text('Hello')
    );
  }
}
```

***Where is the problem? and How can I fix this?***

Comment: Show the code where `SplashScreen` is used.

Comment: I went to SplashScreen from main() and then go to Homepage(). main() => SplashScreen()=> Homepage()

Comment: Any specific exception ?

Comment: @AbirAhsan What are you using for Navigation? `Navigator`? Please post the code you are using.